# Generator issue in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I was trying to understand generators in Python and implemented this:

```
def yfun():
    print("into y fun ... ")
    for x in range(1,6):
        print("tryin to yield : {}".format(x))
        yield x

yieldVar = yfun()

for val in yieldVar:
   print("value generated -> ", val)
```

The output comes as below:

```
into y fun ...
tryin to yield : 1
value generated ->  1
tryin to yield : 2
value generated ->  2
tryin to yield : 3
value generated ->  3
tryin to yield : 4
value generated ->  4
tryin to yield : 5
value generated ->  5
```

Can you please explain why is the function being called again and again ? Isn't the variable supposed to have the values and iteration should be done on generator variable ?

Comment: When you call the function, it gives you a generator object. Iterating through that object executes the code in your `yfun` definition that yields the values.

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: What makes you think the function is called again and again? After all, `into y fun` is printed only once.

Comment: yeah, thats exactly what is was trying to understand, but the way output is generated "tryin to yield " and "value generated " they must not have come in between each other

Answer (score 4):

The function is **not** called again and again you can see that by the fact that `"into y fun ..."` is only printed *once*.

What is happening is the generator, which you get by calling the function containing the `yield`, is being advanced (i.e consumed) by the for loop.

```
yieldVar = yfun()  # call yfun and get a generator
```

While the generator continues to yield values, the loop runs and prints the elements you've yielded.

Comment: thanx for your reply, but now I am not able to understand that why is the generator object not being created at once and being assigned to the "yieldVar" ??
what i am trying to say is that, should not it be like .. when i assign yieldVar the value from the function yfun(), a generator should be created and assigned to yieldVar, thereby when i iterate over the generator using the second for that i have written giving the output as 

value generated ->  1 \n
value generated ->  2
........

Answer (score 1):

When you call a generator function, a *generator object* is returned. Not a single value like a normal function. This is an object that can be used for lazy evaluation.  Each generator object has a method named `__next__()`. This allows Python to repeatedly yield a value from the *generator object* - not the function - `yieldVar` multiple times by calling `__next__()`.

Comment: So that means the line " yieldVar = yfun() "  is being lazily evaluated when i iterate over the variable and doesn't do any operation until it reached that point ??

Comment: @SirTesla Exactly.

Comment: @SirTesla Glad to help!